# Hive query for fetching the data

Tags: hiveql

**org**   **site_id**  **d_id**
ABC          001           1
ABC          001           2
ABC          002           3
ABC          002           1

e.g I have this table,in this for org ABC and site_id 001 d_id 3 is missing and for site_id 002 d_id 2 is missing so i want to write a hive query in such a way that it should add the missing d_id's for that particular site and display it.

Comment: There are 2 basic options but it depends on what your real data look like. is site_id really in NNN format (and if so what is the relevant range)? is d_id really a sequential number  (and if so what is the relevant range)?

Comment: d_id column is not a squential number and site_id is in NNN format, random numbers can be there for both the columns..now can u tell what options u have ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  s.org 
       ,s.site_id
       ,d.d_id

from            (select distinct org,site_id from mytable) s
        join    (select distinct org,d_id    from mytable) d
        on      s.org = d.org
;
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.